# What is the best and most optimized way to return a filestream from a .NET WCF SOAP service?

Tags: .net, wcf, soap

To give some background, i have a WCF SOAP service in .NET that needs to return pdf files. This service will be used by multiple application, many times in a day. The size of the files returned varies from 10KB to 10MB. Also, there is no shared location where the file can be kept and the path can be returned. It can be done using byte[], but that will increase the load on service, which I want to avoid. Any suggestions are welcome.

Application is hosted as a windows service. It is being used mostly by Java Clients. When I am trying to directly return the file stream, at client side the return type does not get mapped to a proper class and returns a null object in an automatically generated empty class. Only in the case when I returned byte[], it was able to read the file.

Comment: How is your application hosted? I.e. web app, windows service, etc?

Comment: You can directly return a Stream object in WCF. Would this help?

Comment: Application is hosted as a windows service. It is being used mostly by Java Clients. When I am trying to directly return the file stream, at client side the return type does not get mapped to a proper class and returns a null object and an automatically generated empty class.

Comment: - Is there any exception (under the hood) like `SerializationException`?

Comment: - What is your return type?
    - FileStream is not serializable. 
    - Streams should be transferred into a data structure. See Remarks on this [MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: What is the problem with byte[]?
    - Load you mentioned is the cost of the serialization itself, which is inevitable for a SOAP service.

Comment: If you can reach the service via WCF SOAP, you should be able to reach a http service as well, so you can store PDF files on service side and share via http/ftp..

Comment: Thanks everyone for replying.
@Kaan - Byte[] works fine, my only concern is that if the file size is too large, it might cause a problem reading the whole file into memory. You are right, filestream is not serializable, hence not able to read it, although it doesn't give any exception, just a null value. 
I am looking for some alternate, which allows me to optimize the packet size, transfer time as well as the service load.

Comment: @Rj1705, I think that at the end of the day, if you want the client to have the file, then you need to pass it over the wire. In the absence of a second method of transfer, there's no way to avoid it (or think of it this way--if you do do pass a file stream object, how does the data end up on the client's machine? Magic? No, the file has to go along for the ride if the user is going to read it.)

Answer (score -2):

Message Transmission Optimization Mechanism (MTOM) is a mechanism for transmitting large binary attachments with SOAP messages as raw bytes, allowing for smaller messages.

please refer : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa395209.aspx
 for more details.

Comment: Does this answer the question that was asked?  If it does, you might want to explain how.

Comment: you need to apply messageEncoding as "Mtom".  <wsHttpBinding>
    <binding name="WSHttpBinding_IUpload" messageEncoding="Mtom"/>
</wsHttpBinding>

Comment: MTOM is a very good solution. Was considering it earlier, but in my case the file sizes are variable and MTOM seems to be further increasing the size for smaller files. Maybe by adding some threshold value, I can use it.